# C++ How to create Read&Writeable null session Pipe?

Tags: c++, winapi

**1. I want to create read&writeable null session pipe.**

To Create Anonymous Pipe, Registed \.\pipe\AnonymousPipe With Null Session _T(""), _T("")

```
SECURITY_ATTIBUTES sa = {0};
```

`hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(tszServer, PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT, PIPE_UNLIMITED_INTANCES, sizeof(DWORD), 0, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, &sa);`

I dont want to use powershell to grant read&write properties.

**2. How to client connect to server**
Simpel Code : LOCALHOST
Server created : \.\pipe\Anonymous
Client created : \.\pipe\Anonymous

If server ip is 192.168.56.150 then client ip is 192.168.56.192, how the client connect to server?

It is right to change **"\.\pipe\Anonymous"** into **"\[SERVER_IP_ADDRESS]\Anonymous"** ?

**3. Reason**
My local pc netstat anop TCP|find "LIST" result here.

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       904    
TCP    0.0.0.0:9930           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       176    
TCP    127.0.0.1:5152         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1788    
TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1892    
TCP    127.0.0.1:9983         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1504    
TCP    127.0.0.1:39778        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1892
```

**Distinctly there is no 445 port opening.**

But Client can connect to server **without 445 port** opneing. **Why?** and **How?**

Ref : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813414/how-to-create-an-anonymous-pipe-that-gives-access-to-everyone

Comment: An anonymous pipe can't be connected to, you can only use the two handles (and duplicates thereof) returned at creation.  Corollary: you can't have an anonymous pipe across a network, it's only for IPC within a single machine.

Comment: Oh, they're using *anonymous* to mean it allows *unauthenticated access*.  Wrong word, *anonymous* already has a very specific meaning with regard to pipes and that isn't it.

Comment: Worse than that, they're using 'anonymous' to mean a pipe that has a name that can be registered. OMG @BenVoigt

Comment: Thankyou "Ben Voigt" and "EJP". But if I create Anonymous pipe as PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, I can read and write data via pipe. only 1 problem remained. how the client can connect to specified server. Help me. Thankyou.